# Адаптивный слайдер для сайта

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap

[image: Нужно реализовать данный слайдер]

Ребята задача такая, слайдер зациклен, переключение слайдера должно быть при помощи нижнего меню в самом нижу на картинке и также prev и next (стрелками). Индикаторы вверху по возможности. При этом всем должна быть адаптивность.
Помогите пожалуйста решить данную задачку.

Comment: Сам недавно добавлял к себе на сайт слайдер, долго думал каким способом это сделать и остановился на Slick.js Отличный слайдер получился, а функций хватает что-бы воплотить все ваши прихоти, можете и вы к нему присмотреться!

Comment: SlickSlider, OWLSlider вполне подойдут. Первый предпочитаю больше.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('.slider-nav').slick({
  dots: true,
  infinite: true,
  speed: 500,
  fade: true,
  cssEase: 'linear'
});   
      
 $('a[data-slide]').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var slideno = $(this).data('slide');
   $('.slider-nav').slick('slickGoTo', slideno - 1);
 });
  
 $('.slider-nav').on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide, index) {   
  var a = nextSlide +1;  
  $('a[data-slide]').removeClass("active");
  
  if($(this).find('.slick-slide').hasClass('slick-active')==true){
    $('a[data-slide="'+a+'"]').addClass("active");
  } 
  
  
});
```

```css
body{
  background:#ccc;
}
.main {
  font-family:Arial;
  width:500px;
  display:block;
  margin:0 auto;
}
h3 {
    background: #fff;
    color: #3498db;
    font-size: 36px;
    line-height: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 2%;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
.action{
  display:block;
  margin:100px auto;
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
}
.action a {
  display:inline-block;
  padding:5px 10px; 
  background:#f30;
  color:#fff;
  text-decoration:none;
}
.action a:hover{
  background:#000;
}

a.active {
    background: #00ff45 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.5.9/slick.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.5.9/slick-theme.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.5.9/slick.min.css">
 


<div class="main"> 
  <div class="slider slider-nav">
    <div><h3>1</h3></div>
    <div><h3>2</h3></div>
    <div><h3>3</h3></div>
    <div><h3>4</h3></div>
    <div><h3>5</h3></div>
  </div>
  <div class="action">
    <a href="#" data-slide="2">Рулоны</a>
    <a href="#" data-slide="3">Бумага</a>
    <a href="#" data-slide="4">Диспенсеры</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: круто,огромное спасибо

Comment: Еще есть вопрос, а как к ссылкам меню action сделать активные ссылки?Связать со слайдером?

Comment: Всмысле чтобы при активном слайде подсвечивалась соответствующая слайду кнопка?

Comment: да, именно так)

Comment: Ну например можно попробовать так: найти активный слайд, вычислить его index  и присвоить кнопки с таким же индексом класс active а к классу уже дизайн. Могу написать точно но позже, сейчас не у ПК.

Comment: Или посмотреть по класса, присваивается что-нибудь или нет

Comment: хорошо жду,пока сам попробую,по тому как ты написал

Comment: не удалось решить самому,жду помощь)

Comment: Ок, позже буду, напишу

Comment: хорошо,буду ждать

Comment: я так понимаю уже без вариантов?не знаешь как помочь?

Comment: @Ivan Знаю, времени нет писать, дела кое какие были. Обновил

Comment: спасибо огромное все отлично)